# Figure out how to read integers into ASCII in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, char, ascii

I have a `.txt` file filled with numbers. I want to put all the numbers into an array.

After they are in the array, a function will turn the numbers into their assigned ASCII characters.

When all the numbers are read, all the numbers in the `.txt` will create a picture using their ASCII characters.

Ex. `numbers.txt` file contains:

`6 99 3 52`

The first number is the time the next number will be printed, then 99 is the ASCII number which will be `'c'`.

So 'c' will be printed six times, and then the program reads the next pair of numbers.

The part I'm having trouble with is writing the function to read the first number and the second number, and making the first number represent the times the next number will be repeated.

Comment: Is there a requirement to use an array?  Can `std::string` be used instead of an array?

Comment: I was advise to use an array to hold all my number since their will be around 150 pair of numbers in the input.txt. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I feel generous today:

```
int quantity;
int char_code;
while (std::cin >> quantity >> char_code)
{
  char c = static_cast<char>(char_code); // Formality.
  for (int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << c;
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

I use `static_cast` to state that I am narrowing an integer to a character.  I'm also using a character variable so that `std::cout` will print the character instead of the integer representation.

Maybe this might be faster, using `std::string`.  The speed gain is that the characters are generated into memory, then printed.

```
while (std::cin >> quantity >> char_code)
{
    std::string text(quantity, static_cast<char>(char_code));
    std::cout.write(text.c_str(), quantity);
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

In the above loop, the `std::string` constructor creates a string with repeats of the given character.  Since the quantity is known and in memory, a *block* write can be used.  Usually with a block write, the time spent formatting is removed by directly outputting from the memory to the console.

Comment: `std::cout.write(quantity, text.c_str());` will not work, as [`cout.write()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) takes a `char*` to a buffer, and a `std::streamsize` for the buffer size.  You need to use `std::cout.write(text.c_str(), text.size());` instead, or simply `std::cout << text;`

Comment: Thank you for the review.  Corrections made.